# Windows Computer Stuck On Loop

Tags: windows, windows-update, desktop, dell-inspiron

a while ago I was notified that my computer did not have enough space to update so I cleared some space and deleted some of my apps and tried again. It worked and it started updating, I went to sleep because it was the night for me. The next day, I come to my computer and on the screen I see it say: "Undoing changes made to your computer". I was so confused about what happened and I thought it would fix itself in a few hours. I checked back in 2 hours and it said the same thing. It actually restarted a couple of times and the same thing happened. I search it up online and people told me to go to "Safe Mode". I tried multiple ways. Turning off and on the computer about 8 times, Press F11 on startup, and none of it worked. I thought I had to wait and it would probably fix itself but it's been two days and the same thing is happening. Will I have to buy a new computer? Please comment on this post.

Comment: Windows 10???..It can be fixed but is very complicated, do you have important data on the hard drive?

Comment: Shut it down (forcefully if necessary), then when off, hold the Shift key down and press the start button. Start in Safe Mode and reduce more space (move to USB hard drive) and try again.

Comment: @Moab No, I don't have important data on it.

Comment: @John Shift power on does not work for me? F8 does.

Comment: John has the right idea if you can get into safe mode, try holding F8 when you power up.

Comment: @Eniola - Try either method for Safe Mode. The trick is to reduce space used

Comment: @John I tried that but it didn't work. I think it's because when my computer startup it usually shows this "floppy diskette seek failure" error but I usually just press F11 to continue and then my computer would boot up. Could that be the reason it isn't working?

Comment: Try booting to BIOS and disable Floppy Drive or move it lower in the start order  and then see if you can get into Safe Mode.

Comment: @John Ok, I'll try that

Comment: @John Ok, I fixed the Floppy Drive thing but now it is saying "System Battery Voltage is Low". Do I need to like move it to another plug or someting

Comment: You can leave the AC connected to charge the battery, but with AC connected, then battery voltage should not affect starting.

Comment: @John So, I should just wait? And I have a desktop so I don't think there is a battery

Comment: Thanks. Replace the CMOS battery on the system board. That is what the message is pointing to. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @John Wait, so I will have to buy a new CMOS battery if I want to fix that error? And I'm gonna try booting to safe mode now.